# Don´t find Omni Interaction Configuration and OmniStudio Settings

Tags: omnistudio

I'm wondering if I need any license or if I need a different kind of org.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Omni Interaction Configuration**

As per documentation(https://docs.vlocity.com/en/Deploy-Industries-CPQ-in-LWC-with-OmniStudio-Enabled.html) it states 'Use this procedure if you have an OmniStudio license enabled before installing CME in your org.'

If you want omnistudio object configuration as well, then you should be having the licenses before install/upgrade the Package .

Also review [Omni Interaction Configuration Settings](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=ind.v_health_omni_interaction_configuration_settings.htm&type=5).

For **OmniStudio Settings** you would need to have have Vlocity license/subscription.

Review [Install and Configure OmniStudio](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=ind.v_health_t_install_and_configure_omnistudio_475954.htm&type=5), [OmniStudio Settings](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.os_omnistudio_settings.htm&type=5).

If you still have issues reach out to your Account Executive for provisioning.